# How do I set a system-wide API hook in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, api-hook

Does anyone know about system-wide API hooking with Delphi?

I downloaded madCodeHook, but it doesn't have any source, so I don't want use it; I want to program it myself.

I found [an article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx), but it is in C++. Please help me to write it in Delphi 2010.

Comment: madCodeHook definitely comes with source code if you buy it.

Comment: But @TOndrej, he wants to write it himself. 350 euros is pretty expensive for code you don't even plan on using.

Comment: And the author of madCodeHook won't just give the code to anyone due to security concerns. If you buy if you don't get the code. You have to buy it extra and prove that you will use it with good intents. At least that was the case two years ago.

Comment: @Rob: I understood "it doesn't have any source, so I don't want use it" as "I don't want to use it because there is no source code".
I was only trying to show that the assumption "it doesn't have any source" was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phoenix, you can try [uallCollection](http://uall.cheat-project.com/uallCollection/) library, is written in delphi 7 (i've tested in  delphi 2007 and it works ok) , and comes with an set of examples wich can download from [here](http://uall.cheat-project.com/uallCollection/Files/Examples.zip) and full [sourcecode](http://uall.cheat-project.com/uallCollection/Files/uallCollection.zip). the only drawback is has not been updated since 07-07-2006, but personally i've tested this library  even on Windows 7 and it works ok.

Comment: i tray uallCollection but it only obtain  local api hook.
i want to inject a dll into system process (Hook Api Functions across system)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use hook procedures (global : entire system; or local : a single program or thread).

Basically, you'll be calling the following procedures :

- The SetWindowsHookEx function : to install a hook (monitor system event)
- The hook function : which is the procedure to be called by windows when the event we "hook" to happens.
- The UnhookWindowsHookEx function : to remove your hook

Here is a simple example of a local hook monitoring keyboard entries:

```
//setting up the hook;
//kbHook is a variable of type HHook (unit Windows);
//kbr_Hook is the procedure that will be called once the event happens;
kbHook:=setwindowshookex(WH_KEYBOARD,@kbr_Hook,0,GetCurrentThreadID());
```

MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx

good luck

Comment: +1 because this IS correct. Some people might consider this incomplete, because Phoenix basically requested "source code", but that doesn't make this answer wrong.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: No, it's not correct. The question is about API hooking not hooking APIs. Hooking APIs are one of several possible ways to have your code (DLL) loaded into other processes - which is one of the required steps - but it doesn't solve the problem of API hooking (intercepting API calls).

Comment: In Mo3ez's defense, Phoenix *did* tag the question with `setwindowshookex`.